# WCF Service with Username and password

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, wcf-security

A little new with WCF services when using username and passwords. I followed the tutorial found at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/96028/WCF-Service-with-custom-username-password-authenti in order to protect my web service with a username and password.

My Config file is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="NewBehavior0" name="TService">
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="ITechnology" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="NewBinding0">
          <security>
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="NewBehavior0">
          <serviceCredentials>
            <clientCertificate>
              <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust" />
            </clientCertificate>
            <serviceCertificate findValue="Server" storeLocation="CurrentUser"
          storeName="TrustedPeople" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="TService, Services1"/>
          </serviceCredentials>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Now i can view the WDSL in my browser and i know the certificate works as expected locally. When i connect to the service using the WCF test tool it doesnt prompt me for a username and password.

According to the link i posted and following ive not even done the final step (adding the code to pass in the username and password) but i can still connect to the service and retrieve all the data.

What have i missed out and how could i restrict the service where only a username and password allows the user/service to retrieve the data?

Edit 1:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="NewBehavior0" name="TechService">
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="ITechService" />
       <endpoint address="TechService.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="ITechService" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="NewBinding0">
          <security>
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="NewBehavior0">
          <serviceCredentials>
            <clientCertificate>
              <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust" />
            </clientCertificate>
            <serviceCertificate findValue="Server" storeLocation="CurrentUser"
              storeName="TrustedPeople" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="TechService, Services1"/>
          </serviceCredentials>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Your service element and endpoint element should have the name and contract attribute to be fully qualified names i.e. namespace.TService and namespace.ITechnology. According to your config your endpoint is not using a proper binding mechanism. It should be wsHttpBinding or basicHttpBinding with transport security

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a quick review of the linked CodeProject page, your config file seems to be a bit off (as it does not indicate that any endpoints are actually using a client credential type).

The "NewBinding0" specifies clientCredentialType="Certificate" but the article indicates the value should be:

```
<binding name="NewBinding0">
    <security mode="Message">
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
    </security>
</binding>
```

Also, the Service definition only defines a “mex” (metadata) endpoint.  You most likely will want to define an wsHttpBinding.. endpoint, which utilizes the corrected binding that specifies clientCredentialType="UserName".

```
<endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NewBinding0"/>
```

Hope this helps.
Regards,

Comment: Thanks i have edited my original post and have included under Edit 1 the latest config file but its still not working as expected. Please note im under the impression when i connect to the service i would be prompted for a username/password or similar before connecting to the service?

Comment: Based on the Edit 1 configuration file, the bindingConfiguration still does not seem to be set (bindingConfiguration="").  You would need to set the bindingConfiguration="NewBinding0" in order for the binding security mode to apply.